# How can I combine the first x columns and the last y columns in a .csv file

Tags: regex, perl, csv, awk

I have a .csv file where I need to remove a bad column. This column contains "extra" delimiters. So the content of column 10 has commas in it. They are not double quoted. So I need to combine the first 9 columns with the last 33 columns. That way the "extra" columns on the line cause by the use of commas in column 10 will be dropped. 
Can anyone give me a regex example with awk, cut, perl anything that will allow me to "fix" this bad data?

Thanks

Here is what I have:

```
field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8,field9,field10,field11,field12,field13,field14,field15,field16,field17,field18,field19,field20,field21,field22,field23,field24,field25,field26,field27,field28,field29,field30,field31,field32,field33,field34,field35,field36,field37,field38,field39,field40,field41,field42,field43,field44,field45
```

field10 is a comment field and some records have commas in the data so it throws off the import process since instead of thinking there are 45 fields it thinks there are 48 or 50 etc.

So I need to have the first 9 fields, and from the back 35 more fields.
I tried Ed's answer but it didn't "cut" and combine properly

```
$ sed -r 's/(([^,]+,){9}).*(([^,]+,){33}[^,]+)$/\1\3/' headers.example.csv 
field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8,**field9,2,field13**,field14,field15,field16,field17,field18,field19,field20,field21,field22,field23,field24,field25,field26,field27,field28,field29,field30,field31,field32,field33,field34,field35,field36,field37,field38,field39,field40,field41,field42,field43,field44,field45
```

So any further suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Post some example and also what you have tried to solve it.

Comment: It will be much easier to help you if you follow the suggestion from @Jotne and give us a few lines from the files you're working with and an example of the output you want. It's hard to visualize from just a description.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe didn't understand right, and your question is realy lack of the "good question" attributes, but try the next:

```
csv="./bad_csv_file.csv"
paste  -d, <(cut -d, -f 1-9 "$csv") <(rev "$csv" | cut -d, -f1,33 | rev) > new_csv.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to print the first 10 columns and the last 33 columns. You can do that with awk:

```
BEGIN { FS=","; ORS=" " }
{ for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
      print $i
  for (i = NF-32; i<=NF; i++)
      print $i
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a simple substitution on a single line, just use sed:

```
$ sed -r 's/(([^,]+,){9}).*,(([^,]+,){34}[^,]+)$/\1\3/' file
field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8,field9,field11,field12,field13,field14,field15,field16,field17,field18,field19,field20,field21,field22,field23,field24,field25,field26,field27,field28,field29,field30,field31,field32,field33,field34,field35,field36,field37,field38,field39,field40,field41,field42,field43,field44,field45
```

You can use the same RE in awk or perl if you prefer, of course.